# Failed opening sunrise.php for inclusion

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions

So I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: include_once(/var/www/wp-content/sunrise.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/wp-includes/ms-settings.php on line 18

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/var/www/wp-content/sunrise.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/wp-includes/ms-settings.php on line 18
```

I assumed that the file sunrise.php wasn't there... it is.
I assumed that the permissions were wrong... they're not (I went 777 just to be safe).

I'm out of ideas. Why can't ms-settings.php see sunrise.php? It's definitely where it should be: /var/www/wp-content/sunrise.php

(If I remove sunrise.php, I just get a blank screen, no warning/errors, just nothing).

Here's my `ls -l` of the wp-content folder:

```
drw-r--r-- 4910 apache apache 81920 Oct  7 17:42 blogs.dir
-rw-r--r--    1 apache apache  3304 Oct 21 15:10 blog-suspended.php
drwxrwxr-x    4 apache apache  4096 Sep 23 20:43 documents
-rw-r--r--    1 apache apache    30 Oct 21 15:10 index.php
drwxrwxr-x   31 apache apache  4096 Oct 21 15:10 plugins
-rwxrwxrwx    1 apache apache  1559 Oct 21 15:10 sunrise.php
drwxrwxr-x    8 apache apache  4096 Oct 21 15:10 themes
drwxr-xr-x    2 apache apache  4096 Oct  3 16:06 upgrade
drwxr-xr-x    7 apache apache  4096 Oct  2 16:10 uploads
```

Any thoughts/ideas?

Comment: You say sunrise.php is in the correct location. Just to confirm, what does "pwd" on that wp-content folder return?

Comment: @lwitzel: It returns "/var/www"

Comment: Wait, when you're in the wp-content directory you showed above, "pwd" returns "/var/www"?

Comment: Also, what are the permissions of the wp-content folder? You could run "ls -al" to see it...

Comment: Sorry, no, my mistake @lwitzel. It was "/var/www/wp-content". Permissions for the folder are rw-r--r--... I'll try upping them.

Comment: Okay, that's closer... Upping the permissions on wp-content shows me most of the site (whereas before, there was nothing below the errors). However, the errors still remain...

Comment: As a long shot, you might try upping the permissions on the dirs at every level.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39671/discussion-between-lwitzel-and-matt-grande)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the sunrise.php file down a level, to "uploads".

Comment: Moving it up a level (and adjusting the include_once to reflect that) fixed the issue. I don't know why (wp-content is where it's supposed to be), but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps apache is running in a jailed environment.
What do you get if you put this in:

```
echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Have you tried doing a relative include (i.e ../)

Comment: I put that in the `ms-settings.php` file and got '/var/www/wp-includes' as expected. Changing to a relative include change changed the path in the error message to "../wp-content/sunrise.php". Any other thoughts?